# How to retrieve session values in Sightly/HTL?

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I am using Sightly/HTL as the templating language in my AEM project (AEM version 6.3). As Sightly provides a lot of context objects, two of them being : request backed by  org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest and currentSession backed by   javax.servlet.http.HttpSession, I am trying to access some session parameter values in my sightly file by doing something like below:

```
${request.session.attribute @ mySessionAttribute}
```

or

```
${currentSession.attribute @ mySessionAttribute}
```

but am not able to get that value. Does anybody has any idea about how to do it?

Comment: This is not possible via HTL only, you’ll need to creat a java/js use class or preferably a sling model (easy to implement with samples from a quick google search) Also, please read the HTL specification https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md

Answer (score 1):

In HTL/Sightly you cannot call arbitrary methods with parameters, it's a limitation by design. Since the `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` API does not expose attributes as a map you can't access them as `${currentSession.attributes['mySessionAttribute']}` so you will need to be creative about it:

*script.html*

`<sly data-sly-use.attr="${'attrib.js' @ session=currentSession, name='mySessionAttribute'}">${attr.value}</sly>`

*attrib.js*

`use(function () {
    return {
        value: this.session.getAttribute(this.name)
    };
});`

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass arguments to methods in HTL like this and I would not recommend doing it anyway.

One way to solve this issue is to use a Sling Model:

```
@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class)
public SessionModel {

    @ScriptVariable
    private Session currentSession;

    public String getMySessionAttribute() {
        return this.currentSession.getAttribute("attributeName");
    }
}
```

HTL:

```
<div data-sly-use.sessionModel="com.mypackage.SessionModel">
    ${sessionModel.mySessionAttribute}
</div>
```